# lower() was called on None

Tags: django, authentication

I have created a custom function to create custom username in a class Inheriting DefaultSocialAccountAdapter. The code is as follows.

```
def _build_username(self,data):

        from allauth.utils import generate_unique_username

        if(not data.get('username')):

            first_name=data.get('first_name','').lower()

            last_name=data.get('last_name','').lower()

            suggested_username = (f"{first_name}{last_name}",)

            username = generate_unique_username(suggested_username)

            return username
```

But it throws lower() was called on None

I was trying to convert the name to lowercase because that is how our database supports usernames. This happens when i try to perform google login authentication method.

Comment: Post the full traceback...

Comment: That means the value in `data` was `None`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because, the data may contain first_name or last_name key but its value may be None. So you can add a condition check to ensure its not None

```
def _build_username(self,data):
    from allauth.utils import generate_unique_username
    if(not data.get('username')):
        first_name=data.get('first_name','')
        last_name=data.get('last_name','')
        l=[]
        if(first_name):
            l.append(first_name.lower().strip())
        else:
            l.append('')
        if(last_name):
            l.append(last_name.lower().strip())
        else:
            l.append('')
        suggested_username = (f"{l[0]}{l[1]}",)
        username = generate_unique_username(suggested_username)
        return username
```

Answer (score 3):

This is possible if the `'first_name'` is in `data` and associates the key with `None`, so `{'first_name': None}` for example.

You can use the `or` operator to replace this with the empty string, so:

```
def _build_username(self,data):
    from allauth.utils import generate_unique_username
    username = data.get('username')
    if not username:
        first_name=data.get('first_name') or ''
        last_name=data.get('last_name') or ''
        username = generate_unique_username(f'{first_name}{last_name}'.lower())
    return username
```